# How do I tell HLS to use hls-class-plugin?

Tags: haskell, ide, cabal, haskell-language-server

I was looking for how to discover the names of the methods of a type class in a Haskell file using the [HLS](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server).

Searching around I found [this page](https://haskell-language-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#code-actions) where the code action "Add missing class methods" is mentioned.

I would like that feature to work in my IDE (I use Vim + YouCompleteMe), so I've just installed `hls-class-plugin` via `cabal install hls-class-plugin`¹, which succeeded, but also ended with a warning:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@ WARNING: Installation might not be completed as desired! @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The command "cabal install [TARGETS]" doesn't expose libraries.
* You might have wanted to add them as dependencies to your package. In this
case add "hls-class-plugin" to the build-depends field(s) of your package's
.cabal file.
* You might have wanted to add them to a GHC environment. In this case use
"cabal install --lib hls-class-plugin". The "--lib" flag is provisional: see
https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6481 for more information.
```

The the question is, how do I tell the HLS to make use of this library?

I do read that

> You might have wanted to add them as dependencies to your package. In this
> case add "hls-class-plugin" to the build-depends field(s) of your package's
> .cabal file.

but which `.cabal` file? After all I don't want this feature to be available in a project... but simply every time I open a Haskell file.

---

(¹) In principle I would have thought I should install it via `cabal install --lib hls-class-plugin`, but that just errored out:

```
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' is 70 days old.
Run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available packages.
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' is 70 days old.
Run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available packages.
Resolving dependencies...
Error: cabal: Cannot build the package hls-class-plugin because none of the
components are available to build: the library is marked as 'buildable:
False'; and the test suite 'tests' cannot be built because cabal does not
currently support building test suites or benchmarks of non-local dependencies
```

Comment: Configuring this plugin is more about configuring vim than configuring HLS. Which language server integration setup have you gone with?

Comment: @DanielWagner, YCM

Comment: [This part of the YCM documentation](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe?tab=readme-ov-file#lsp-configuration) discusses how to send configuration options to the language server, and [this part of the HLS documentation](https://haskell-language-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#generic-plugin-configuration) describes what configuration options you may send. I don't know where in the YCM documentation it describes which key to press to trigger this kind of code completion, though.

Answer (score 0):

The `haskell-language-server` package has to be built with the `class` flag set. Then *`haskell-language-server` package* will make itself depend on `hls-class-plugin`, link to it, and use it when the executable runs. You can't tell HLS to use any plugins it wasn't built with at runtime.

In order to set a flag on the `haskell-language-server` package, you have to build it yourself. Also, if a flag not set by default (a plugin is not enabled by default), that probably means that plugin hasn't been updated to the version of GHC you've built HLS for, so there's no guarantee a build you do yourself will work. Anyway, to build `haskell-language-server` from source, I believe the workflow is like this (it's been a while and the build's quite finicky anyway)

1. Clone the repository into some directory and enter that directory.
2. Take a look at the flags (they're defined in `.cabal` file, but the list on [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hls-class-plugin) is *probably* also up-to-date.
3. Issue `cabal configure -fflag1 -fflag2 ...` for the flags you want. You may (probably?) need to set `-fignore-plugins-ghc-bounds`.
4. `cabal install` should build the package, if possible. It might not be possible!
5. The above command, if it works, puts a `haskell-language-server` executable... somewhere (the location is configured in your cabal config, and I think it can be set with `--installdir`).
6. Take that executable (it'll actually probably be a symlink to the executable) and put it in the right place for your editor to find it. You should probably include the GHC version in its name as it is specific to the GHC version it was built with.

Comment: To expand on this: you probably should *not* follow these instructions and build haskell-language-server yourself. hls-class-plugin is listed as a Tier 2 plugin [here](https://haskell-language-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/support/plugin-support.html#current-plugin-support-tiers), which should mean that it's available by default unless something has gone unusually wrong in HLS development.